# Terminal emulators and btsync behavior

Tags: xterm, terminal-emulator, konsole, rxvt

I've downloaded the BitTorrent Sync binary. The program only provides a Web UI interface. I'm trying to create a window for the daemon, using a terminal emulator, because I don't need an always online `btsync`. When I execute:

```
cd ~/.btsync/; konsole -e "./btsync --nodaemon"
```

the `btsync` daemon EXITS when i CLOSE the konsole window clicking the X button. When I run:

```
cd ~/.btsync/; uxterm -e "./btsync --nodaemon"
```

the `xterm` window STILL RUNS when I click the window close button. When I execute:

```
cd ~/.btsync/; urxvt -e "./btsync --nodaemon"
```

and I close the `rxvt` window, the `btsync` DAEMON STILL RUNS in background.

I was trying to use `urxvt` to assign an icon and a title to the "daemon window" and my only solution was execute this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/.btsync/
echo BitTorrent Sync Web UI: http://127.0.0.1:8888/gui/en/index.html
echo
exec ~/.btsync/btsync --log ~/.btsync/sync.log --nodaemon
```

using this command line in a `.desktop` file:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/urxvt -fn "xft:Inconsolata" -icon ~/.btsync/btsync.png -iconic -title "BitTorrent Sync" -e btsync; /bin/kill $(cat ~/.btsync/.sync/sync.pid)
```

using `/bin/kill` to close the daemon when the `rxvt` window closes. My question is: somebody knows why `konsole`, `xterm`, `rxvt` doesn't share the same behavior in this case? I can't use `x-terminal-emulator` to generalize my code for this reason, and I have multiple clients with different Linux desktop environments in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit upon terminal close is caused by one of two things:

1. Getting an EOF on stdin
2. Receiving a SIGHUP

In my testing, both xterm and konsole do this, so its unclear why the behavior would differ, unless you're getting randomly broken signals from a recent (though now fixed) nVidia bug (see [After upgrade, X button in titlebar no longer closes xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107331/after-upgrade-x-button-in-titlebar-no-longer-closes-xterm)).

You could use `nohup` to make sure neither exit.

I will note, however, that the `-e` syntax various between terminal emulators. For example, `konsole -e 'sleep 60'` will exit immediately; `xterm -e 'sleep 60'` will wait 60 seconds. If you remove the quote marks—passing each argument as a separate argument—it'll work in both terminals.

```
$ konsole -e sleep 60    # works
$ xterm -e sleep 60      # works
$ konsole -e 'sleep 60'  # FAILS
$ xterm -e 'sleep 60'    # works
```

Strictly speaking, Debian Policy says `x-terminal-emulator -e` must work like it does in xterm, but then specifies a behavior that xterm had at one point (it'd fail in that final case)... but xterm changed its behavior. See [Debian Bug 648271, *11.8.3 "Packages providing a terminal emulator" says xterm passes -e option straight to exec*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648271).

So, it may simply be that you're using `-e` wrong; you should be doing:

```
cd ~/.btsync/; konsole -e ./btsync --nodaemon
```

Note the lack of quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your answer was useful. Thanks. Seems that the propietary btsync is the problem because doesn't process SIGHUP.